# Issue with a Syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have code for query for a table which looks for normal in a column and then displays the value in another column.

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
>   LINE 7: FROM public."Process"

The code is as follows :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN "Process.Amount 1" = 'Normal'
             THEN "Process.time 1"
        END AS "Process.time 1",
        CASE WHEN "Process.Amount 2" = 'Normal'
             THEN "Process.time 2"
        END AS "Process.time 2",
FROM public."Process"
WHERE 'Normal' IN ("Process.Amount 1", "Process.Amount 2");
```

I think it must be the route to the process table and have tried various ways of writing it but have the same error.

The `public."Process"` is what I have used on all other queries and that worked.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
names-#         END AS "Process.time 2",
names-# FROM public."Process"
```

You're writing `SELECT a,b, FROM`. Try deleting that extra comma.

Comment: thank you mromani i am new to this so am making loads of mistakes. Ihave another error, and stuck on the following:   SELECT CASE WHEN Process.Amount_1  = 'Normal'
THEN "Process.time 1"
END AS "Process.time 1"
CASE WHEN Process.Amount_2  = 'Normal'
THEN "Process.time 2"
END AS "Process.time 2"
FROM public."Process"
WHERE 'Normal' IN ("Process.Amount 1", "Process.Amount 2");
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CASE"
LINE 4:        CASE WHEN Process.Amount_2  = 'Normal'    can you please help

Answer (score 3):

There are several mistakes within your code. First one is to remove comma after last declaration of column to retrieve within SELECT statement.

Secondly, when you have a table name created with quote marks and you do the same for columns, you need to put quotations around each object name, not put them all together, whenever you want to reference them. For example if you have a table `"Process"` and column `"Amount 1"` then:

This is invalid

```
"Process.Amount 1"
```

This is valid

```
"Process"."Amount 1"
```

That said your query should look like:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN "Process"."Amount 1" = 'Normal' 
       THEN "Process"."time 1" END AS "Process.time 1",
  CASE WHEN "Process"."Amount 2" = 'Normal'
       THEN "Process"."time 2" END AS "Process.time 2"
FROM public."Process"
WHERE 'Normal' IN ("Process"."Amount 1", "Process"."Amount 2");
```

I wonder though about your where condition - it's valid but depending on what you actually want to achieve may not be the best way to write it from right to left ;)

Also, as a general rule, **please avoid quote marks around database objects**, since it introduces more problems than it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra comma in line below :

```
    END AS "Process.time 2",
```